# how to display selcted photo id in url as pid=123 in nextgen gallery in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, nextgen-gallery

I am using nextgen gallery plugin in my wordpress site for displaying gallerys.

At present i am getting like this

```
www.abc.com/photos/venky-photo-gallery-1097.html/nggallery/image/venky3
```

i want like this

```
 http://www.chitramala.in/photos/varun-tej-photos-178077.html?pid=15453
```

How to implement this format. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose you have to create a template and call all photos in that template. Here you can get the id and pass it as

http://www.chitramala.in/photos/varun-tej-photos-178077.html?pid=$var['id']

then get it like $_GET['pid']

Comment: is there any settings in nextgen gallery plugin?